# Understanding nilpotent and fundamental matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Why does $$ \alpha I + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ u & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ have a fundamental matrix given by
$$e^{\alpha t}.\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ ut & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I've just learnt that $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ u & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ is a nilpotent matrix (and what that means)

How does all this relate together? Thank you

Comment: What is a fundamental matrix? The exponential?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, this is how the question is posed but it doesn't give a definition of a fundamental matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U:= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ u & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Prove that $U^2=0$.

Thus $\exp(t(\alpha I + U))=e^{\alpha t}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^nU^n}{n!}=e^{\alpha t}(tI+tU)=e^{\alpha t}.\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ ut & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Fred you are a great man

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks